# How to skip segments in videos. Repeat it to the end?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruXZM.jpg)I would like a solution for this. I have 1 video of random length. I split the video length into segments of two main groups, X and Y, alternating. where X and Y are times in seconds. How to get output video with only X or Y segments? I want to adjust it without having to split the video and then merge them. I would like a command to run if possible. Is there any solution to the above method? (attached image is illustrated). Thanks for care.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/50770731/5726027 and adjust values. You can also use the between or gt function in place of lt

Comment: Thanks very much. By the way, can you tell me the difference between gt and it?

Comment: gt = greater than; lt = less than

Comment: Do you think I use the greater value? With GT also for smaller values with lt. I've tested it and found it not entirely correct on time. Is it necessary to add additional commands to make it work better?